# What does 'self' mean in /proc?

Tags: linux

In this question: [What is the file descriptor 3 assigned by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41421/what-is-the-file-descriptor-3-assigned-by-default) is used `/proc/self/fd`, which dereference to `/proc/32157/fd`. So it is `pid`? And why cannot I `echo $self`? I have never seen `self` before.

Comment: It means always the current process. For example, an `ls -l /proc/self/` will be the `/proc/<pid>` directory of the `ls` process listing it. :-) Btw, doesn't the dupe answer your question? I think, yes.

Comment: `/proc/self` is a file. `$self` is a variable. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/proc` tree is a window into the operating system which is dynamically generated.  When a process refers to `/proc/self`, the kernel translates `self` using the caller's `pid`.  So that saves the process from doing a pid-lookup on itself, but you could get that same node of information by doing `/proc/{pid}` if you know the `pid` already.

One of the beauties of Unix is how it unifies all these things under `/` a root namespace and makes them behave like files and directories, even if they're not real physical file systems.

And you can't echo `$self` because that's a different concept entirely: to do an `echo $[varname]` is a shell thing: your shell has "environment variables" that maintain state.  That has nothing to do with the `/proc` filesystem.

Comment: See also here (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) under the section "/proc/self". It says: `When a process accesses this magic symbolic link, it resolves to the process's own /proc/[pid] directory.`